# Are all subbasis subsets of basis?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In topology, each element of basis $\{B_k\}$ can be expressed as finite intersections of elements of subbasis, i.e.
$B_k=S_{n_1}\cap ...\cap S_{n_m}$

Does the meaning of "finite intersections" also include situations such that an element of basis can be expressed as one of elements of subbasis? In other words, "are all subbasis subsets of basis?"

Comment: Yes, singletons (and the empty set) are finite sets, so $S_{n_1} = \bigcap \{ S_{n_1}\}$ is a finite intersection of subbasis elements (as is $X = \bigcap \varnothing$).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! There's no problem anymore!